# detect UIWebView form submission in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, form-submit

I've read the posts here, but cannot quite adapt them to my needs.  I have:

```
-(IBAction) abouthtml
{
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
CGRect webViewRect = frameWebSpace;
UIWebView *myWebPage=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewRect];
[myWebPage loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:myWebPage];
}
```

This displays fine, but my "Return to Program" submit button in about.html is not working.

I've tried, as suggested in posts here:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request 
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) 
{
     ....
```

But obviously, nothing links myWebPage to webView.   Can someone suggest what I'm missing?
Do I need to make webView a delegate of myWebPage?   Confused, but hopeful...

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the delegate of `UIWebView` to be the object that implements `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, `[myWebPage setDelegate:self]`, assuming that class that adds the subview is the one you want to receive the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` message

Answer (score 0):

Set `myWebPage`'s delegate to the object that implements (in your case probably *self*)

```
-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```